Unnecessary records being recorded in JMeter
I have recently started studying Jmeter. In HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder I have set filter and was recording the blazedemo website but I am getting some other records apart from php records. This is not there in the videos I am watching and I have the same setting as the video mentions. As a beginner I don't know what these records are and how to filter this. Please help.

I searched for it everywhere, asked the instructor of jmeter and tried chatgpt. Nothing helped.

There is "Requests Filtering" tab in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, first of all click "Add suggested Excludes" button:

and if it doesn't help add a Regular Expression which will filter out all the "unnecessary" requests
More information: Excluding Domains from the Load Test

Isn't it interesting that the recommended paths to exclude include all static assets.   You will never be able to find a defect in the cache plan or extra load from missing assets if you never ask questions about these items under load.

If you record the static assets JMeter: 1. Will replay the requests sequentially so the network footprint will be different from the real browser. 2. Cache-Control headers will not be respected. There is a special checkbox which instructs JMeter to download embedded resources using parallel thread pool and HTTP Cache Manager which simulate real browser's behaviour. More information: JMeter Web Testing: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses

You don't have that issue in other tools.  It's something for a tester to be aware of when designing a test and picking a tool

You don't have this functionality in the majority of tools, if tester is not aware of how does the tool work and isn't capable of using a sniffer tool to ensure that he simulates real life scenario he should quit IT and become a rickshaw

There is a sbstantial break between commercial and open source tools regarding default capabilities in this area (browser threads, management of assets, repect for cache headers, etc...).   The default on the commercial front is included capability.  On the open source front, not.  Similar for monitoring, analysis and reporting capabilities.
